angular PrimeNg <p-multiselect> with loader
I'm loading data in primeng  dynamically. It works fine as the user searches for data and the options  array is being loaded.
All I want is to be able to display a loader icon instead of the search icon, while data is being loaded.
I checked documentation and found [dropdownicon] property, which does not change the icon.
Is there any way to change the icon in primeng multiselect?
Angular 17,
"primeng": "^17.7.0",
<p-multiSelect 
    [options]="cities" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" 
    placeholder="Select Cities"
    optionLabel="name" 
    display="chip" 
    [showClear]="true" />



NOTE : Adding                 [dropdownIcon]="'pi pi-spinner pi-spin'" works in p-dropdown, but not in p-multiselect

use the loading parameter on click search to change the loading to true
in HTML use this parameter to change the icon like [dropdownIcon]="loading ? 'pi pi-spin pi-spinner' : 'pi pi-search'"

You can create a custom directive, that inserts the spinner using javascript.
I listen for ngOnChanges to trigger when the boolean that controls loading is changed.
I listen to the dropdown open, only then search icon is available for modification.
TS:
    @Directive({
    selector: '[searchLoader]',
    standalone: true,
    })
    export class SearchLoaderDirective {
    replace = '';
    @Input() searchLoader = false;

    constructor(private multi: MultiSelect) {}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.toggleLogic();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.multi?.onPanelShow?.subscribe(() => {
        this.toggleLogic();
        });
    }

    toggleLogic() {
        console.log('1');
        const magnify: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('searchicon');
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.classList.add(
        'p-multiselect-trigger-icon',
        'pi',
        'pi-spin',
        'pi-spinner'
        );
        span.style.position = 'absolute';
        span.style.right = '11px';
        span.style.top = '13px';
        if (magnify) {
        if (this.searchLoader) {
            magnify.style.display = 'none';
            magnify.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', span);
        } else {
            magnify.style.display = 'inline-flex';
            const spin: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(
            'span.p-multiselect-trigger-icon.pi-spin'
            );
            spin.remove();
        }
        }
    }
}

HTML:
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-multiSelect
    [searchLoader]="searchLoader"
    [options]="cities"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"
    [loading]="false"
    optionLabel="name"
    placeholder="Select Cities"
    display="chip"
    [showClear]="true"
  />
</div>

Stackblitz Demo
